# macOS NSExtensionMainStoryboard fails to load

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

Unlike the many questions trying to create an iOS extension with a .xib, I am trying to do the exact opposite of creating a macOS extension with a StoryBoard. When Xcode creates an App Extension target for my macOS projects, it only has a .xib and a NSExtensionPrincipalClass for the ViewController in the .xib

So I created a New -> File -> Storyboard, and I added [NSExtensionMainStoryboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW14) to the plist and the name of the StoryBoard without extension, I get the vague Widget Simulator error:

```
"TodayExt[76374:5145083] Failed to load extension view controller"
```

I have confirmed: the StoryBoard name, the StoryBoard custom class, the target membership for the StoryBoard, NSExtensionMainStoryboard is *directly below* NSExtension.

From my plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>TodayStoryboard</string>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointVersion</key>
        <string>2.0</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.widget-extension</string>
    <key>com.apple.notificationcenter.widget.description</key>
    <string>TodayExt</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but a work around. [The answer on Apple Dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28012) said "you could always define a custom storyboard and use a bit of glue code to embed that in your root view controller."

For those wondering what that 'bit of glue code' would be, inside your *ExtensionController, you would add something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myStoryboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: NSStoryboard.Name("MyStoryboard"), bundle: Bundle.main)
    let myStoryboardVC = myStoryboard.instantiateInitialController() as! MyStoryboardViewController
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = true
    self.view.addSubview(myStoryboardVC.view)
    self.insertChildViewController(myStoryboardVC, at: 0)
```

I would still love to know the proper way to do this without glue.